# FOREIGN KEYS related to a specific index

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mariadb

When I try to DROP a specific index, I have the classic error message :

> Cannot drop index 'IX_XXXXXX_YYYYYY':
>
> needed in a foreign key constraint(MySqlException)

I know I can uncheck FOREIGN KEY constraint like this :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

But that's not what I want.

I'm not looking for a way to DROP the index.

I'm looking for a way to find which FOREIGN KEY is using the index I am trying to DROP?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` ?

Comment: the error will tell you which table/column is using said foreign key

Comment: Actually, no. The error you see is the one I get... no more no less

Comment: In SQL Server you can write a Query which gives you everything you need on the FK... sad to see it doesnt exist in MySQL yet... but i can hardly believe it...